# Lambda Functions for Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

My goal is to find a construct within Z3Py which allows me to:
(1) Write propositions as a function of a variable. For eg theoretically, if I define P(x) = x < 3, then the code should allow me to access P(u) for some other variable u.
(2) And Z3 should be able to solve and find a model for such a construct.

I thought Z3's 'Lambda' function theoretically made sense. However with this construct neither can I do (1) or (2). As a concrete eg, suppose I have the following code:

```
u, x = Ints('u x')
P = Lambda( [x], x < 5 )
I = Lambda ([x], x < 3)
C1 = Not(Implies(P.body(), I.body() ))
s = Solver()
s.add(C1)
r = s.check()
print(r.__repr__())
s.add( Implies(P(u), u == 2) )
```

Run this code to get the output:

```
unknown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testfile.py", line 20, in <module>
    s.add( Implies(P(u), u == 2) )
TypeError: 'QuantifierRef' object is not callable
```

There are two issues to fix here:

(1) Why does r._ *repr*_() have 'unknown' stored and not 'sat' i.e. Why isn't Z3 solving this system?

(2) In the final line, how can I get the predicate u < 5 from P i.e. in lambda calculus terminology, how do I do application of a function to a variable in Z3Py? Clearly P(u) does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of modeling, you should simply use a regular python function:

```py
from z3 import *

def P(x):
    return x < 5

def I(x):
    return x < 3
```

Then, to do the proof `Q(x) => P(x)`, you'd use a quantifier:

```py
dummy = Int('dummy')
C1 = ForAll([dummy], Implies(I(dummy), P(dummy)))
prove(C1)
```

This prints:

```
proved
```

Regarding your specific questions:

(1) Adding `Implies(P.body(), Q.body())` means something completely different. If you run:

```py
from z3 import *
x = Int('x')
P = Lambda( [x], x < 5 )
I = Lambda( [x], x < 3 )
s = Solver()
s.add(Implies(P.body(), I.body()))
print(s.sexpr())
```

You'll see it prints:

```
(assert (=> (< (:var 0) 5) (< (:var 0) 3)))
```

where `:var` is an internal free-variable generating function. This isn't an object you should be passing back and forth to z3; in fact, I think you're becoming a victim of the loosely typed nature of z3; this isn't a construct that really make much sense at all. Long story short, you should never look at `P.body()` or `I.body()` in your own code. I'd ignore the `unknown` result in this context; the input is more or less meaningless, and z3 spits out a nonsensical answer. A better system should've checked and complained about this; but this is not a strong point for z3's Python API.

(2) If you use a regular function, this isn't really a problem at all; because you're just doing regular application at the Python level. You *can* apply a lambda-bound value by directly calling it as well, though you need the notation `P[u]`. (Lambda's are similar to arrays in z3.) So, something like:

```py
from z3 import *

u, x = Ints('u x')
P = Lambda([x], x < 5)
I = Lambda([x], x < 3)
s = Solver()
s.add(Implies(P[u], u == 2))
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

will print:

```
sat
[u = 2]
```

which is what you were looking for I think.

### Multiple arguments

If you want to model a lambda with multiple arguments, the easiest way is to think of it as a nested construct. That is, you store a new lambda at each index. Here's an example:

```py
from z3 import *

dummy1 = FreshInt()
dummy2 = FreshInt()
P = Lambda([dummy1], Lambda([dummy2], dummy1 < dummy2))

s = Solver()

x, y = Ints('x y')
s = Solver()
s.add(P[x][y])
print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

This prints:

```
sat
[y = 1, x = 0]
```

Note that the above also demonstrates the use of the `FreshInt` function, which avoids name-clashes by providing a unique name each time it is called.

Comment: What would be notation for a double lambda? For eg if A= Lambda([a, b], b == a + 1), then how do i get the application of A on x and y? Z3 doesn't seem to be accepting A[x,y] or A[x][y] - gives a syntactic error.

Comment: Added a two argument lambda example. You can generalize to arbitrary number of variables in the obvious way.